# ensure fields hold values as more fields are added rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form for `JobDeliveryCost` where a user can add delivery costs. Every time the user adds one, an additional field is created to add another. at the moment, I have a form and I display the fields.

```
-jdc_array=(@job.job_delivery_costs.any? ? [@job.job_delivery_costs,@new_delivery].flatten : [@new_delivery])
            -jdc_array.each do |jdc|
              = simple_form_for [:admin, @job, @new_delivery] do |f|

                %tr
                  %td
                    = jdc.timing
                    = f.input :timing, collection: JobDeliveryCost::TIMINGS, :include_blank => "please select"
                  %td
                    = f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title), :label_method => :title,:value_method => :id
                  %td
                    -if jdc.new_record?
                      =f.submit "add"
                    -else
                  %td
                    = jdc.cost_per_unit
                    = f.input :cost_per_unit
                  %td
                    = jdc.quantity
                    = f.input :quantity
```

Instead of displaying the inputted value above each form entry, how do I get the fields to hold their value instead?

Also, how would I display the value of this

```
  = f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title), :label_method => :title,:value_method => :id
```

as it is a child attribute of the DeliveryCost model?

For extra enfo I have added my controller and relevant models

```
class Admin::JobDeliveryCostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_job

  def index
        # raise @job.inspect

    if get_deliverable
      @jdc_array=(@job.job_delivery_costs.any? ? [@job.job_delivery_costs,@new_delivery] : [@new_delivery])
      # raise @jdc_array.inspect
      @new_delivery = @deliverable.job_delivery_costs.build


    end
    set_job_delivery_cost
  end


  def create
    if @job
        @job_delivery_cost = JobDeliveryCost.new(job_delivery_cost_params)
        @job_delivery_cost.job = @job
      if @job_delivery_cost.quantity.nil?
        @job_delivery_cost.quantity = 1
      end
            # raise @job_delivery_cost.inspect
      if @job_delivery_cost.save
        flash[:success] = "Delivery Costs Added"
      else
        flash[:error] = "Delivery Costs not Added"
        end 
    else
        flash[:error] = "Couldn't find the Job."
    end
    redirect_to admin_job_job_delivery_costs_path(@job)
    end


  def destroy
    set_job_delivery_cost 
    if @job.present? && @job_delivery_cost.present?
      @job_delivery_cost.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Job delivery cost removed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't find the record"
    end
    redirect_to admin_job_job_products_path(@job)
  end

  private

  def set_job
    @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])
  end

  def set_job_delivery_cost
    @job_delivery_cost ||= JobDeliveryCost.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def job_delivery_cost_params
    params.require(:job_delivery_cost).permit!
  end

  def get_deliverable
    return @deliverable if @deliverable
    if params[:contact_id].present?
      @deliverable = Contact.find_by(id: params[:contact_id])
    elsif params[:client_id].present?
      @deliverable = Client.find_by(id: params[:client_id])
    elsif params[:job_id].present?
      @deliverable = Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])
    end
    @deliverable
  end

end
```

delivery_cost.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: delivery_costs
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  title         :string(255)
#  unit          :string(255)
#  cost_per_unit :float
#  created_at    :datetime
#  updated_at    :datetime
#

class DeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base

  UNIT_DAY='day'
  UNIT_HOUR='hour'
  UNIT_MILE='mile'
  UNITS=[UNIT_DAY,UNIT_HOUR,UNIT_MILE]

  has_many :job_delivery_costs
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_delivery_costs

  validates :cost_per_unit, presence: true
  validates :unit, inclusion: UNITS
  validates :title, presence: true
  before_destroy :survive_if_jobs

  private

  def survive_if_jobs
    jobs.empty?
  end
end
```

JobDeliveryCost

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: job_delivery_costs
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  job_id           :integer
#  delivery_cost_id :integer
#  cost_per_unit    :float
#  quantity         :integer
#  timing           :string(255)
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#

class JobDeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base
  TIMING_INSTALL='install'
  TIMING_BREAKDOWN='breakdown'

  TIMINGS=[TIMING_INSTALL,TIMING_BREAKDOWN]

  belongs_to :delivery_cost
  belongs_to :job
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to:1}
  validates :timing, inclusion: TIMINGS
  #validates :cost_per_unit, presence: true

validate :validate_cost_per_unit
  validate :check_associates
  # validate :quantity_default
  before_save :init


  private

  def check_associates
    associated_object_exists DeliveryCost, :delivery_cost_id
    associated_object_exists Job, :job_id
  end

  def validate_cost_per_unit
    if delivery_cost and cost_per_unit.blank?
      self.cost_per_unit=delivery_cost.cost_per_unit
    end
    return false if cost_per_unit.blank?
  end

    def init
      if self.quantity.nil?
        self.quantity = 1
      end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are going to want to use javascript to solve your problem. There is an excellent [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) that discusses nested model forms but it also shows you how to build javascript for dynamically adding field elements with links.

Instead of links, you will most likely want to register an onChange event (meaning the user changed data in the field) to add another field.